# A question about p-adic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to learn about $p$-adic numbers and I have some questions.
I tried to learn about the motivation from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), which was very clear and with some straightforward examples.

But I'm having trouble understanding the following:

- If we take an algebraic approach to construction, we first construct $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and them from it we construct $\mathbb{Q}_p$ by taking it to be the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. The thing I don't understand is the zero in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$. For example, if we have $p=7$ we have that (0,7,7,7,7,...) and (0,7,7,7,56,56,56,....) both have no inverses. Are they both zero in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?
  Is this the same thing as 7 and 14 being both zero in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$?
- Every $x\in \mathbb{Q}_p$ can be written as $x=p^{-n}u,$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}, u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*.$ Why is this true? So I understand that $x=\frac{a}{b}, a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_p,$ so we have $a=p^ku, b=p^mv, m,k\in\mathbb{N}, u,v\in \mathbb{Z}_p.$ But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I'm not sure of your notation here: Does $(0,7,7,\ldots)$ mean $0+7\times 7^1+7\times 7^2+7\times 7^3+\cdots$. If not, then what?

Comment: For example $(2, 8, 8, 35, 35, ...)= 2 + 2\cdot 3 + 0\cdot 3^2 + 1\cdot 3^3 + 0\cdot 3^4 +...$
Sorry, I thought this was standard.

Comment: So $(0,7,7,7,\cdots)$ just means $7$? So what does $(0,7,7,7,56,56,\ldots)$ mean?. I am baffled by this  since $56\not\equiv7\pmod{7^4}$.

Comment: Look at the analogous situation in $\mathbf Z$: $3$ and $7$ have no inverse *in* $\mathbf Z$.  Would you consider them 0? Of course not.

Comment: If every nonzero element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ had an inverse, then there wouldn't be a reason to distinguish taking its field of fractions to obtain $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no they are not zero.it doesn't have an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ but this doesn't mean it should be zero $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a ring like $\mathbb{Z}$ and has many non-zero,non-invertible elements.

we can describe invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_7$: a sequence is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ if and only if it's first component is not divisible by seven. the reason is that every element of $\mathbb{Z}/7^n$ which is coprime with 7 has a unique inverse. so you can take the inverses componentwise and they are compatible with each other.

by this fact you can see that every element of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ can be written in the form $7^nu$ where u is invertible.now your second question is this fact in another language.